# Why screen resolution remains 640x480 when I close a game?

Tags: games

I played Lugaru, the game went in Full screen mode, but when I closed the game, the screen resolution was still 640x480. It happened with Neighbours From Hell also, using Wine, and well... Almost every game i tried in fullscreen mode. Is it normal? Is there a fix for that?

Comment: Please do not put (SOLVED) to the title. Accepting an answer is the correct way to mark a question solved here. Also your UPDATE did not add anything valuable to your question, so I reverted [your recent edit](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/237018/3).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fullscreen handling in Linux is rather broken and lots of games are causing such troubles. Easiest workaround is probably to use `xrandr` to bring things back into the proper resolution (put that in a script and make it an icon in the top/left corner of your screen for easy restore):

For a single monitor setup that would be simply something like:

```
xrandr --output DFP2 --mode "1680x1050"
```

For a multimonitor setup it would look like:

```
xrandr \
 --output DFP2 \
   --mode "800x600" \
   --panning "800x600+1280+0/0x0+0+0" \
 --output CRT1 \
   --mode "1280x1024" \
   --panning "1280x1024+0+0/0x0+0+0"
```

Running `xrandr` without any option give you a list of supported modes and available displays.

Note there is also a bug in `xrandr` itself, sometimes the monitor size will adjust, but the mouse movement will still be locked to the old resolution, to fix that just run `xrandr` a second time.

Alternatively you can also set `wine` to emulate a virtual desktop, this will prevent games from going fullscreen and force them to be confined to the Wine virtual desktop window. The setting available in `winecfg` and then `Graphics->Emulate a virtual desktop`.

Answer (score 1):

This happens to me sometimes when exiting a game. It seems random. I am not sure if it's a problem with Wine or the original game code (probably both).

For me, the command to go back to my native resolution was:

```
xrandr --output HDMI-0 --preferred
```