# Warzone 2100 occasionally zoomes my screen largly,how to fix it?

Tags: unity, games

sometimes after playing `Warzone 2100` for long time,when i exit the game,the desktop **screen just zooms largly**,and only 1/4 th screen is visible.the top bar is visible completely,but is inoperable.

i would have shared the screen shot,but the save or copy buttons are in the invisible 3/4 th part of the screen.

There is an answer already present [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/237018/why-screen-resolution-remains-640x480-when-i-close-a-game).But **it is not perfect solution**,because it only allows me to restart the system,which causes certain important tasks(like downloading files) to end.

I wish to know **if there is another way to zoom out the screen**,which will allow me to use my pc correctly(and not just allow me to restart it).

Comment: These two issues [may be related](http://askubuntu.com/questions/237018/why-screen-resolution-remains-640x480-when-i-close-a-game)

Comment: this should be an answer instead.got my answer,hope it works.

Comment: You should be able to hold Alt and click and drag to move a window. Then you should be able to take a screenshot.

Comment: I tried this way, but it doesn't work.